# KeystoneJS, tracking updatedBy/updatedAt

Tags: keystonejs

Been pulling my hair, google tells me nothing. Can't for the life of me understand how they intend 'track' to work.

From the documentation, I assumed it would be as straight forward as this:

```
Truth.add({
    title: { 
        type: Types.Textarea, 
        required: true 
    }
    track: {
        updatedBy: true
    }
});
```

However, the above solution renders this:

```
Error: Fields must be specified with a type function
```

All i want is for my model to store who last updated the item. Is this not how 'track' is intended to work? What am i missing...

Comment: Note that the `track` key needs to be given as an option when creating, not as a field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define this in the list schema rather than the model fields.

You can either set `track: true` to enable all the meta fields or to an object for specific ones.

```
var Truth = new keystone.List('Truth', {
    track: true // Enables all field
    track: {updatedBy: true} // Enables updatedBy field only
});
```

These will then appear at the bottom of the item page.